# 2 layer SQL join

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm pretty new to sql.

I have the following db schema:

```
Customers
    CustomerID number
    Name string
    Address string
    Country string
OrderDetails
    OrderDetailID number
    OrderID number
    ProductID number
    Quantity number
Orders
    OrderID number
    CustomerID number
    OrderDate string
    OrderValue string
Products
    ProductID number
    ProductName string
    Price number
```

I need to get the CustomerID and Quantity for all those that have ordered a particular product name = "oil"

So far I can get the quantity by

```
select OrderDetails.Quantity
FROM Products
INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID
where Products.ProductName = 'oil'
```

I can get the CustomerID by following Products.ProductID -> OrderDetails.ProductID -> OrderDetails.OrderID -> Orders.OrderID -> Orders.CustomerID but I am unsure how to express this in sql.

EDIT:
I'm looking for a single table like:

```
 CustomerID | Quantity 
-----------------------
     1          10
     4          40
     5          1
```

## Testing:

I'm using the SQL to regular expression calculator [here](http://clotho.uom.gr/relax/calc.htm#) using the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/moonraker595/e544065626aa90f472841be2dede8724)

Comment: It's not clear what your expectations are - are you after a single row per customer, and hence a total order quantity, or do you want to see individual orders / quantities?

Comment: Please explain what a "regular expression calculator" has to do with a simple SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select customers.name,sum(OrderDetails.Quantity) as tot_qty
FROM Products
INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID
inner join orders on orderdetails.orderid=orders.orderid
inner join customers on orders.customerid=customers.customerid
where Products.ProductName = 'oil'
group by customers.name
```

Comment: hi, please see update, i get Error at line 1: aggregation columns must be named

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the distinct, use `group by` instead.

Use [`sum()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) [aggregated function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to consolidate all orders

```
select sum(OrderDetails.Quantity) as total, OrderDetails.CustomerID
FROM Products
INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID
INNER JOIN Orders O ON O.OrderId = ON.OrderId
where Products.ProductName = 'oil'
group by Order.CustomerID
```

Comment: hi, i get : Error at line 5: Expected ",", ";", "except", "fetch", "having", "intersect", "limit", "offset", "order", "union" or end of input but "w" found.

Comment: @WhatTheWhat oh, my bad, see the edit

Comment: i now get: `Error: could not find column "OrderDetails.CustomerID" in schema [Products.ProductID : number, Products.ProductName : string, Products.Price : number, OrderDetails.OrderDetailID : number, OrderDetails.OrderID : number, OrderDetails.ProductID : number, OrderDetails.Quantity : number]`

Comment: @WhatTheWhat see the edit

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to aggregate the quantities per CustomerId.

Since you only require the `customerId` there's no need to join to the `Customer` table.

Note also the use of short meaningful aliases makes the query less verbose:

```
select o.CustomerId, Sum(od.Quantity) Quantity
from Products p
join OrderDetails od on od.ProductID = p.ProductID
join orders o on o.orderid = od.orderid
where p.ProductName = 'oil'
group by o.CustomerId;
```

Comment: I get an Error: aggregation columns must be named

Comment: I'm not familiar with that error, the above shouldn't generate any error.  Can you create a DBFiddle and demonstrate? @WhatTheWhat

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back. Have a look and the testing section in the question which details how what i'm trying to do, thanks

Comment: I don't see anything that relates to mysql or any RDBMS.